# Selecting specific indices from a numpy matrix and converting it into a numpy matrix in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to select specific elements from a ndarray. I have the list of row and column indices.

Here I have all_combos which contains a list which was an output of the following code, generating all combinations of a list

```
for i in range(len(Combo)):
    all_combos.append(list(itertools.combinations(Combo[i],2)))
```

This gave me a list of lists which contain the row and columns of my desired matrix

I tried the below mentioned code to select the values from the matrix Trans and appended it to a list. This resulted in cluster_values being a list of list.

```
for j in range(len(Combo)):
    for i in all_combos[j]:
        cluster_values[c].append(Trans[i[0]][i[1]])
    c=c+1
```

My final goal is to plot these values into a networkx graph. But it accepts only numpy matrix as argument. So I wanted to figure out what is the best way to capture the indices as well as the value from Trans matrix so that i can use it to plot the graph.
Thanks in advance